# Is it possible for a properly divided factorial to become a square?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n>1$  and let $Q$ denote the product of all prime numbers $p$ with $\frac{n}{2}< p\leq n$ .

Is it true that $\frac{n!}{Q}$ is a perfect square for finitely (or infinitely) many $n$?

Comment: If there's a prime between $n/4$ and $n/3$, then its cube will exactly divide $n!$, so no perfect square. And if $n$ is large enough, it's guaranteed there will be a prime between $n/4$ and $n/3$. So, only finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sharpening of Bertrand's Postulate says that for any $c\gt0$ and any $m\gt m_0(c)$ there is a prime between $m$ and $(1+c)m$. It follows that for all sufficiently large $n$, there is a prime $p$ between $n/4$ and $n/3$. The multiples of $p$ up to $n$ are precisely $p$, $2p$, and $3p$, so $n!/Q$ is divisible by $p^3$ but not by $p^4$, so, for $n$ sufficiently large, $n!/Q$ is not a square.